# @RemoteAction example in salesforce, href not redirecting to correct url

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting the below error when working with @RemoteAction program.

```
The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must 
begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an
underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.
```

[image]

When I click on Opportunity Name, I see the below error comes.

[image]

I think it should simply go to the

```
https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/0067F000002blM5QAI
```

What changes do we need to do in the following code?

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityRemoteActionController" showHeader="true">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getStageJS(){
            var oppStage= document.getElementById("{!$Component.theFm.oppStage}").value;  
            OpportunityRemoteActionController.getOpportunityDetails( oppStage,

            function(result, event){
              var html = '<table border="thick solid">';
              html = html + '<caption><b>Opportunity Details</b></caption><tr></tr>';
              html = html + '<tr><th>Opportunity Name</th>';
              html = html + '<th>Amount</th>';
              html = html + '<th>Account Name</th> </tr>';
              if (event.status && event.result) {
                  for (var prop in event.result) {
                  // important check that this is objects own property not from prototype prop inherited    
                  html = html + '<tr><td><a href="'+ event.result[prop].Id +'">' +event.result[prop].Name+ ' </a>'
                              + '</td><td>'+event.result[prop].Amount
                              + '</td><td>'+event.result[prop].Account.Name
                              + '</td></tr> ';
               } 
                html = html + '</table>';
                $("#opportunityDetails").html(html);
          } else {    
                 alert(event.message);
          }
        }, {escape:true});
    }
     </script>

       <div align="center" width="550px">
          <apex:form id="theFm">
            <apex:selectList value="{!stageName}" size="1" id="oppStage" onchange="getStageJS()">
                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
          </apex:form>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div id="opportunityDetails" align="center">
             <!-- Opportunity details is displayed here. -->    
       </div>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: add a slash to the original href - my mistake on the previous answer, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relates to my previous answer, but I'll put it here - add a `/` to the href to make it a relative url - and perhaps make it `_blank` target too:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/'+ event.result[prop].Id +'">' + '+ event.result[prop].Name +' + ' </a>
```